# SQLite UPDATE ID deletes row

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I am trying to update the values in a table row and give that row the next consecutive ID (I am not the one who decided on this but fact is: When I change the title I need a new ID).

For example:

```
Id | Title
------------
2  | Wonderwall
3  | Lonely Doy
4  | All That She Wants
```

Should become

```
Id | Title
------------
2  | Wonderwall
4  | All That She Wants
5  | Lonely Day
```

I tried updating the Title while leaving the ID the same. This query works flawlessly:

```
result = await database_helper.dbRunQuery(`
    UPDATE Songs 
    SET Title=?,
        LastModified=? 
    WHERE Id=?`, [
        newValue,
        new Date(),
        id
    ]);
```

When I, however, try setting the ID at the same time, the row simply gets deleted without any error messages (apparently SQLite does not throw those on UPDATE statements). This is the code that does not work:

```
result = await database_helper.dbRunQuery(`
    UPDATE Songs 
    SET Title=?,
        LastModified=?,
        Id=?
    WHERE Id=?`, [
        newValue,
        new Date(),
        database_helper.getNextSongID(),
        id
    ]);
```

Is there a reason why it works that way? And also, since I need to update more tables like this: Is there an easier way to auto-increment the Id column (nope, auto-increment is not defined for this table and I cannot change that)? I already have the query

```
SELECT Id
FROM Songs
ORDER BY Id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

for selecting the highest Id in the table, I should just be able to put this in a subquery like `Update Songs Set ..., Id=(SELECT Id ... LIMIT 1) WHERE ...` right?
My SQL has gotten quite rusty I have to admit...

Comment: `update` should not be deleting rows.  How do you know the row is being deleted?

Comment: I am SELECTing after the fact and the row I want to modify is gone

Comment: Wait wait wait. The SELECT includes JOINs with other tables. While these should all be left joins, this might still be the issue. Let me check.

Comment: I missed a single `LEFT` before `JOIN` in the SELECT query, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The query posted above is working as expected; Here's where my error was: I missed the first `LEFT` in this select query.

```
SELECT 
Songs.Id as SongID, Songs.Title, Songs.CreationDate, Songs.LastModified, Files.Path, Files.PageOrder, Files.FileSize, Files.Type, Artists.Id as ArtistID, Artists.Name as ArtistName
FROM Songs 
JOIN Files ON Songs.Id = Files.SongId 
LEFT JOIN ArtistsSongs ON Songs.Id = ArtistsSongs.SongId 
LEFT JOIN Artists ON ArtistsSongs.ArtistId=Artists.Id
```

which was then not showing the ID of the new song because it couldn't be JOINed - here's the fixed version:

```
SELECT 
Songs.Id as SongID, Songs.Title, Songs.CreationDate, Songs.LastModified, Files.Path, Files.PageOrder, Files.FileSize, Files.Type, Artists.Id as ArtistID, Artists.Name as ArtistName
FROM Songs 
LEFT JOIN Files ON Songs.Id = Files.SongId 
LEFT JOIN ArtistsSongs ON Songs.Id = ArtistsSongs.SongId 
LEFT JOIN Artists ON ArtistsSongs.ArtistId=Artists.Id
```